# Axis Code Generating Error: IWAB0399E Error in generating Java from WSDL

Tags: java, web-services, axis

I was generating a web service client with Axis in Eclipse. but got this Error:

```
IWAB0399E Error in generating Java from WSDL:  java.io.IOException: <input ..>, <output ..> or <fault ..> in <portType> with undefined message found. message name is '{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/}insertPurchaseRequest
```

the WSDL is:

```
<definitions xmlns:tns="urn:WebServices11" xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2000/10/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2000/10/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:http="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/http/" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" name="WebServices11" targetNamespace="urn:WebServices11">
    <types>
    <xsd:schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/10/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="urn:WebServices11">
    <xsd:element name="insertPurchaseRequest">
    <xsd:complexType>
    <xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:element name="transaction_reference_id" type="xsd:integer"/>
    <xsd:element name="amount" type="xsd:float"/>
    <xsd:element name="reference_number" type="xsd:string"/>
    <xsd:element name="reference_number" type="xsd:string"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>
    <xsd:element name="insertPurchaseResponse">
    <xsd:complexType>
    <xsd:all>
    <xsd:element name="return" type="xsd:string"/>
    </xsd:all>
    </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>
    <xsd:element name="selectPurchaseRequest">
    <xsd:complexType>
    <xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:element name="transaction_reference_id" type="xsd:string"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>
    <xsd:element name="selectPurchaseResponse">
    <xsd:complexType>
    <xsd:complexContent>
    <xsd:restriction base="soapenc:Array">
    <xsd:attribute ref="soapenc:arrayType" arrayType="tns:objPurchase[]"/>
    </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:complexContent>
    </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>
    </xsd:schema>
    </types>
    <message name="insertPurchaseRequest">
    <part name="transaction_reference_id" type="xsd:integer"/>
    <part name="amount" type="xsd:float"/>
    <part name="reference_number" type="xsd:string"/>
    <part name="reference_number" type="xsd:string"/>
    </message>
    <message name="insertPurchaseResponse">
    <part name="return" type="xsd:string"/>
    </message>
    <message name="selectPurchaseRequest">
    <part name="transaction_reference_id" type="xsd:integer"/>
    </message>
    <message name="selectPurchaseResponse">
    <part name="return" type="tns:objPurchase"/>
    </message>
    <portType name="WebServices11PortType">
    <operation name="insertPurchase">
    <documentation>Add the Purchase record</documentation>
    <input message="insertPurchaseRequest"/>
    <output message="insertPurchaseResponse"/>
    </operation>
    <operation name="selectPurchase">
    <documentation>Get the Purchase record</documentation>
    <input message="selectPurchaseRequest"/>
    <output message="selectPurchaseResponse"/>
    </operation>
    </portType>
    <binding name="WebServices11SoapBinding" type="tns:WebServices11PortType">
    <soap:binding style="rpc" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
    <operation name="insertPurchase">
    <soap:operation soapAction="urn:WebServices11InsertPurchaseAction"/>
    <input>
    <soap:body use="encoded" namespace="urn:WebServices11" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/>
    </input>
    <output>
    <soap:body use="encoded" namespace="urn:WebServices11" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/>
    </output>
    </operation>
    <operation name="selectPurchase">
    <soap:operation soapAction="urn:WebServices11selectPurchaseAction"/>
    <input>
    <soap:body use="encoded" namespace="urn:WebServices11" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/>
    </input>
    <output>
    <soap:body use="encoded" namespace="urn:WebServices11" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/>
    </output>
    </operation>
    </binding>
    <service name="WebServices11Service">
    <port name="WebServices11Port" binding="tns:WebServices11SoapBinding">
    <soap:address location="http://www.emdad-rayaneh.com/WebService/Soap_WebService_emdadpc2/purchase_server.php"/>
    </port>
    </service>
    </definitions>
```

Please Help!

Answer (score 1):

Try add 'tns:' info to portType
You will find others wrong things with wsdl

```
<portType name="WebServices11PortType">
    <operation name="insertPurchase">
    <documentation>Add the Purchase record</documentation>
        <input message="tns:insertPurchaseRequest"/>   << here
        <output message="tns:insertPurchaseResponse"/> << here
    </operation>
    <operation name="selectPurchase">
        <documentation>Get the Purchase record</documentation>
        <input message="tns:selectPurchaseRequest"/>  << here
        <output message="tns:selectPurchaseResponse"/>  <<here
    </operation>
</portType>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but the WebService server is not mine, I want to write a client for this Webservice. I used Axis client generator and got that error. do you think it's the server's fault that I got that error?

Comment: May be, but the soapui tool can generate a helpfull client, I don't know how

Comment: tnx, SoapUI uses Axis or Apache CXF to generate client too

Comment: What about Axis2, I have the same problem